# creating function, outside main() function, for random Number in specific range

Tags: c++, function, random, srand, create-function

I am trying to write a function for a random number in a range decided by the user. I call srand() in int main() with the function RandomNumber defined above.

I know if do the randomnumber equation in main(), while also calling srand() in main(), it works how I want.

This is the program that does not do what I want. The return value is a combination of numbers and letters. I need return of a number in a range determined by the user input. Essentially, I need to create a random number generating function outside the int main() function, then be able to call the RandomNumber inside int main(). I run into trouble with calling srand(time(NULL));. I have to call srand() inside main() or the random number is not generated correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int RandomNumber(int userNum1, int userNum2) {

return (rand() % (userNum2 - userNum1) + userNum1);
}

int main()
{   
    srand(time(NULL));
int userNum1;
int userNum2;
cin >> userNum1;
cin >> userNum2;



cout << RandomNumber << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Even if I call srand() inside the RandomNumber function, it does not work as I want.
/////////////////////////////////////////

This is a program that does what I want, but I am trying to define the function RandomNumber above int main().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;




int main()
{   
    srand(time(NULL));
    int RandomNumber;
    int userNum1;
    int userNum2;
    cin >> userNum1;
    cin >> userNum2;


    RandomNumber = rand() % (userNum2 - userNum1) + userNum1;
    cout << RandomNumber << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////
How can I create my RandomNumber function outside main() and call it insdide  main()?

Comment: "This is the program that does not do what I want." What is the problem? What does your program do? How does that differ from what you want? Please [edit] your question to include more details.

Comment: You really should tag this with the language.

Comment: Watch [this video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/goingnative-2013/rand-considered-harmful) to see why you should avoid `rand()` and avoid modulo arithmetic to get a range. C++ provides much better alternatives for you to use.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is: if `RandomNumber` is a function, `cout << RandomNumber` tries to print the function's address in memory (it's actually unspecified; on some systems, it just prints `1` to acknowledge the fact that the function exists).

To call a function, provide a list of arguments:

```
cout << RandomNumber(userNum1, userNum2)
```

---

Even if a function doesn't get any arguments, you have to provide parentheses to call it. For example:

```
void do_useful_stuff() // no arguments
{
    puts("Useful Info");
}

int main()
{
    cout << do_useful_stuff; // doesn't print anything useful
    cout << do_useful_stuff(); // prints "Useful Info"
}
```

---

In the code which works well

```
RandomNumber = rand() % (userNum2 - userNum1) + userNum1;
cout << RandomNumber << endl;
```

`RandomNumber` is not a function but a number. Printing it will work without any surprises.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the input. I am currently in my first semester of getting a bachelors in programming so I am literally brand new to this at 34 years old. I can use all the help possible, especially since I've never done any kind of programming work of any kind in the past

Comment: I also can only use information that has been presented in the course already, so there are aspects of c++, which is what we're currently learning, that I have yet to learn. Also, for the current project, I have to create and define atleast 5 functions outside main() and int main() can only contain 10 lines of code.

Comment: @ajsmith5150 Constraints such as no more than 10 lines of code in `main` should be stated in your question, not in comments. Comments can come and go, your question should be self-contained with all necessary information needed to formulate an acceptable answer.

Comment: Yes and I would include it in my question if it pertained to the specific question, but I only was asking about creating a function to generate a random number. The part about 10 lines of code was just side talk and did not pertain to the specific question. The answer that is in place is perfect for what I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the most streamlined version, in my opinion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int generateRandomNumber(int lowNumber, int highNumber) {
    int randomNumber = rand() % (highNumber - lowNumber) + lowNumber;
    return randomNumber;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int userNum1;
    int userNum2;

    cin >> userNum1;
    cin >> userNum2;

    cout << generateRandomNumber(userNum1, userNum2) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note the main change here is that you have to call the function and pass it the values that the user enters as parameters. You can just as easily assign the result to a variable rather than just printing it out with cout.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

// Declare the function to generate a random number
int generateRandomNumber(int lowerBound, int upperBound);

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int userNum1;
    int userNum2;

    cin >> userNum1;
    cin >> userNum2;

    int RandomNumber = generateRandomNumber(userNum1, userNum2);
    cout << RandomNumber << endl;

    return 0;
}

// Define the function to generate a random number
int generateRandomNumber(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
{
    int randomNumber = rand() % (upperBound - lowerBound) + lowerBound;
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this fixes the OP's problems.

Comment: I am trying to create that function, RandomNumber, outside the main() function. I need to define ffunctions outside of main for my project.

Comment: I understand what to do now. Thak you. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: To expand on @Code-Apprentice's comment, code-only answers are frowned upon here. You're more likely to get upvotes if you provide explanations alongside the code.

Comment: @ajsmith5150 My comment was for the person that answered. Their code seems to solve your problem, and it will be more helpful with some words that explain why.

Comment: Sorry, its my first time